# How can I diagnose issue with Oracle Data Pump import failing with error 1089

Tags: oracle, docker

I am trying to import a schema into a dockerized container in Ubuntu14.04.  The container is based on [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-xe-11g/), which contains Oracle XE 11g.  The alert log shows nothing about this, and the Trace produced by `impdp` itself just shows the last table script created (which is different each run).

The command I'm using is:

> ```
> /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/impdp myshema/mypass@"(DESCRIPTION\=(ADDRESS_LIST\=(ADDRESS\=(PROTOCOL\=TCP)(HOST\=db)(PORT\=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA\=(SID\=XE)))" PARFILE=/myschema/myschema.par;
> ```

The import proceeds for a while, then at some semi-random point fails with "Oracle error 1089".  It gets partway through creating the tables (repeated runs end at a different table each time).  Connecting to my Oracle instance from another session shows that the instance is still up and working, even after this failure.

```
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Oct 18 15:07:22 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_SQL_FILE_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_SQL_FILE_SCHEMA_01":  MYSCHEMA/********@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))D\=XE))) PARFILE=/MYSCHEMA/MYSCHEMA.par
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYNONYM/SYNONYM
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TYPE/TYPE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DB_LINK
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE

UDI-01089: operation generated ORACLE error 1089
ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3326
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4551
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process ID: 242
Session ID: 23 Serial number: 5
```

My parameter file is:

```
SQLFILE=imp_dir:myschema_import.sql
SCHEMAS=MYSCHEMA 

# ignore storage attributes for tables & use defaults 
TRANSFORM=SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES:n
DIRECTORY=imp_dir 
DUMPFILE=MYSCHEMA_META.DMP 

# set this for some extra tracing:
TRACE=1FF0300 

EXCLUDE=TABLESPACE_QUOTA
EXCLUDE=MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS

REMAP_TABLESPACE=INDEX1:users 
REMAP_TABLESPACE=INDEX2:users 
REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATA1:users 
REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATA2:users
```

Just for completeness, the only untoward lines in the alert log are:

```
Wed Oct 19 11:56:26 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_ora_70.trc:
ORA-27167: Attempt to determine if Oracle binary image is stored on remote server failed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:parse_df failed with status: 2
ORA-27301: OS failure message: No such file or directory
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: parse failed
ORA-27303: additional information: Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
none           101799456 42184988  55159488  44% /
Image consistency checking encountered an error, checking disabled
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Shared memory segment for instance monitoring created
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 3
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on.
IMODE=BR
ILAT =61
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.
Using parameter settings in client-side pfile /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora on machine 11
2c1560d28e
```

This seems to be a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) though, as it occurs every time the database is started up (right from the original docker image), and doesn't seem to affect anything else.

There is a relevant trace log for the import: `XE_dm00_232.trc`.  Nothing seems (by my estimate) unusual in it till the end.  Unfortunately for me, this information isn't really any more helpful than the 1089 error:

```
*** 2016-10-19 11:58:57.861
KUPC:11:58:57.860: Before Listen: consumer = MCP
KUPC:11:58:57.861:  from queue = SYS.KUPC$C_1_20161019115822

*** 2016-10-19 11:58:58.916
KUPM:11:58:58.916: Client count is: 1
KUPM:11:58:58.916: In check_workers...
KUPM:11:58:58.916: Live worker count is:  1
KUPM:11:58:58.916: In set_longops
KUPM:11:58:58.938: Work so far is: 0
KUPM:11:58:58.938: Checking for resumable waits
KUPC:11:58:59.051: Before Listen: consumer = MCP
KUPC:11:58:59.051:  from queue = SYS.KUPC$C_1_20161019115822

*** 2016-10-19 11:59:04.048
KUPC:11:59:04.048: Before Listen: consumer = MCP
KUPC:11:59:04.049:  from queue = SYS.KUPC$C_1_20161019115822

*** 2016-10-19 11:59:08.942
KUPC:11:59:08.942: Error Code: -1089
KUPC:11:59:08.942: Error Text: dequeueMessage ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted
KUPM:11:59:08.942: Error detected by MCP
KUPC:11:59:09.083: Before ENQ: Sending Type: 2022 ID:
KUPC:11:59:09.083:  DG,KUPC$S_1_20161019115822,MCP, ,22,Y
kwqberlst rqan->lascn_kwqiia > 0 block
kwqberlst rqan->lascn_kwqiia  22
kwqberlst ascn 355628 lascn 22
KUPM:11:59:09.194: ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -1089
KUPC:11:59:09.230: Before ENQ: Sending Type: 2022 ID:
KUPC:11:59:09.230:  DG,KUPC$S_1_20161019115822,MCP, ,23,Y
kwqberlst rqan->lascn_kwqiia > 0 block
kwqberlst rqan->lascn_kwqiia  22
kwqberlst ascn 355628 lascn 22
KUPM:11:59:09.231: ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in MAIN
KUPM:11:59:09.231: ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUEUE_INT", line 572
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPM$MCP", line 1072
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPM$MCP", line 857
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     ----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
KUPM:11:59:09.231:       object      line  object
KUPM:11:59:09.231:       handle    number  name
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     0x7b1dd540     15140  package body SYS.KUPM$MCP
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     0x7b1dd540       994  package body SYS.KUPM$MCP
KUPM:11:59:09.231:     0x7b3bbb48         2  anonymous block
KUPM:11:59:09.231: In RESPOND_TO_START
KUPM:11:59:09.231: Killing workers on fatal exception...
KUPM:11:59:09.231: In check_workers...
KUPM:11:59:09.231: Live worker count is:  1
KUPF:11:59:09.233: In FILE_REQUEST_NAK...
KUPF:11:59:09.233: ...sent 0 exit messages

*** 2016-10-19 11:59:11.232
KUPC:11:59:11.232: Before Listen: consumer = MCP
KUPC:11:59:11.232:  from queue = SYS.KUPC$C_1_20161019115822
KUPP:11:59:11.233: Entering kuppkilw
KUPP:11:59:11.233: mso = 0x7a559c60, Error = 39119
KUPP:11:59:11.233: Called ksvhdlshut to kill all workers for this job
KUPP:11:59:11.233: Exiting kuppkilw
KUPV:11:59:11.234: Update request for job: MYSCHEMA.SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01, func: 1
KUPP:11:59:11.272: Action = 1, mso = 0x7a559c60
KUPP:11:59:11.281: Entering kuppkilw
KUPP:11:59:11.281: mso = 0x7a559c60, Error = 31673
KUPP:11:59:11.282: Called ksvhdlshut to kill all workers for this job
KUPP:11:59:11.282: Exiting kuppkilw
root@112c1560d28e:/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace#
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, was not helpful. Database is open, import succeeds partially (1909 objects in `MYSCHEMA`), but still aborts with `UDI-01089`. I'm lost.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin.  I can also `select * from <some_table>` that was imported, and it successfully returns 0 rows (the import contains the schema only - no data).

Comment: Maybe add a `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=SKIP` to your import parameter file and restart the import until it finishes successfully? That doesn't explain it, but it might solve your immediate problem (for now...).

Comment: Thanks, @Martin.  I need this to work automatically (and repeatedly), as part of a CI pipeline though, so while there may be a number of ways to get past this on an ad hoc basis, that won't help me much.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Oracle instance? Any errors in alert log file?

Comment: @JSapkota:  Bouncing the database doesn't give any additional clues.  I edited my question to show the only unusal part of the alert log.  This part is present right in the original docker image though, and doesn't seem like it affects anything.

Comment: Are any trace files generated by the import (under /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace)?

Comment: @AlexPoole:  I added a relevant trace file from the import (there was only 1 "dm" file).

Comment: Thanks; doesn't help a great deal unfortunately. I can't see anything that looks relevant on My Oracle Support. You might need to raise a service request. A couple of thoughts though; what platform and version was the export done from? If you're running this on the DB server can you connect locally rather through TNS; and if you have to use TNS can you use the service name, and maybe (for fun) try easy connect syntax or a TNS alias?

Comment: @AlexPoole:  Export was done from a Win 2008, Oracle 10 instance.  I was trying this import from a different docker container (that the one the server is running on), but that probably wasn't really necessary.  I'm going to give this another shot with a fresh export, and changing the process/Docker files so that the import just runs locally (and maybe then with easy_connect syntax).  If anything interesting develops, I'll update my question (or add an answer).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that running the imports manually worked (sometimes), I realized I can get around the issue by adding an additional delay **after** the database is already "OPEN".

A  30 second delay produces this (a different error):

```
UDI-12528: operation generated ORACLE error 12528
ORA-12528: TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections
```

And a 60 second delay allows the import to proceed successfully.  It seems as though there is something with the database `not-quite-ready` even after the database is open.

This gets around the issue, but I'd prefer a better explanation, or an alternate solution that didn't involve a magical, arbitrary delay to wait for the database to be **really** ready.